# What does `SEA_WS` stands for in antlr grammar?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I know `WS` means white space, but what is the full form of `SEA` in `SEA_WS` in antlr grammar?

```
SEA_WS : (' '|'\t'|'\r'? '\n')+;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably related to "Sea" vs. "Island" parsing modes:

[Switching to island mode on multi-character token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813877/switching-to-island-mode-on-multi-character-token)

In short: a metaphor used when parsing brace-delimited expressions, islands are tokens between delimiters, and sea is everything else.